# How to Upload file using WPF only

Tags: wpf

Greetings to all,

I wonder if anyone knows or has the sample code to upload a file to a server (web server using ISS) without using ftp and using WPF.

Besides I wanted to ask if the file you wish to upload multimedia is possible that before being uploaded to the server you can do a preview before you upload it using the player archivosde average WPF

Thank you very much.

Comment: Upload to what? A web site, a web service, a custom server.. ?

Comment: What exactly has WPF got to do with uploading? Write the uploading code properly and you can slap any interface over it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transmit a file to a server, without using FTP. I suggest you make a little class library that will use a web service on the server to upload stuff.

Answer (score 0):

System.Net.WebClient has an UploadFile method that can upload a file using an HTTP POST [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadfile.aspx).